# Clicklistener for View Group Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewgroup

I am working on android application in which i am using ViewGroup to show my footer in my list view. Now i want to make an listener event for that view group, so user can press that footer. My code to make that footer and view group is given below along with the xml.

```
ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, mListView, false);
                    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);
                    Button headerButton = (Button)header.findViewById(R.id.footerRefreshBtn);
                    mListView.addFooterView(footer);

                    headerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                             Toast.makeText(context, "I am clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }
                    });
// It is not showing toast message on click.
```

XML for footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/footerRefreshBtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Refresh Button"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/gray" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @XaverKapeller thanks for your reply. I am using the above code but the View Group is not clickable. Nothing happen when i clicked it. Please help me out here

Comment: Why are you using `addFooterView(View, Object, boolean)`? Just use `addFooterView(View)`. I think this is the source of the error. Or more specifically the `false` at the end, but I am not sure, just try `addFooterView(View)`.

Comment: @XaverKapeller thanks for your reply. Kindly see my edited code above, i have changed according to your instructions but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find out how to `setOnClickListener` to a footer, but I found a different solution. I think you could use this, just find the `footerRefreshBtn` and set Button's `OnClickListener` only before or after you add footer view. Both ways are working.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, mListView, false);

    mListView.addFooterView(footer, null, false);

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    Button footerRefreshBtn = (Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.footerRefreshBtn);

    footerRefreshBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I am clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

This way, you are only assigning the Button's onClick event.

Nevertheless if you still want to set an onClickListener to a whole footer, you can get footer's layout and set an onClickListener to this layout using the method I mentioned above.